# Early 80's fantasy (ish?) film where some kids are trying to save a magical creature by returning it to the ocean

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to recall a movie I'd seen circa early 90's (via a pre-'tweenified' Disney Channel) and what I recall of it involved kids on a beach or some kind of coast discovering a magical creature (not a mermaid, sea serpent or anything like that, but I want to say it was definitely more like an animal) and are trying save it/return it to the ocean(?), so maybe it was bordering on being eco-conscious as well.

What else I know about it that it was early 80's (for some odd reason, 1983 screams out the most) and that it was European, more specifically I want to say Scandinavian (and I've tried looking for Sweden, Finland, Denmark, The Netherlands... Don't think it'd be from either Greenland or Iceland).

Comment: Finland and the Netherlands aren't Scandinavian ... and did you forget Norway?

Answer (score 2):

This may be *The Water Horse*, a pleasant story of discovering
a foundling magical being... and basically having fun.

The date is 2007, however, and the milieu seems to be Scotland.

Answer (score 1):

*Magic in the Water* might be what you're looking for. It came out in 1995. It's about a couple of kids who discover a lake monster named "Orky" is real and the movie has an environmental message (the bad guy is dumping toxic waste into the creature's lake). But it was set/made in Canada, not Europe.

Here's the trailer that was included on a bunch of VHS releases at the time: